# Coherent sheaves that are isomorphic on every fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $E$ be a line bundle on $X$. Let $F$ be a line bundle on $X\times \mathbb{P}^1$. It is known that, if $p_1^*E|_{X_t}\cong F|_{X_t}$ for every $t\in \mathbb{P}^1$, then we have $F\cong E\boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(k)$ for some $k$.

> **Question.** Can this result be generalized? For example, does it hold when $E$ and $F$ are torsion-free sheaves, and $F$ is flat
> over $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Under the assumption that $E$ and $F$ are of rank $1$ and without the smoothness assumption on $X$, I think this can be shown using the compactified Picard scheme $\bar{Pic}$ of $X$. Roughly speaking, this would follow from the fact that two morphisms $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \bar{Pic}$ which agree on all points of $\mathbb{P}^1$ must be the same.

Comment: @Jef Thanks for comment! Do you have any idea about higher rank case, for example when $E$ and $F$ are both of rank two?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm afraid. It's probably good to start with assuming that $E$ and $F$ are vector bundles, for which I also don't know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the statement is false already for rank $2$ vector bundles.

In fact, take $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Then, it is known **[1]** that there exist indecomposable, uniform rank $2$ vector bundles $F$ on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, namely, indecomposable bundles such that $$F|_{X_t} = \mathcal{O}(a) \oplus \mathcal{O}(b)$$ for every $t \in \mathbb{P}^1$. So, setting $E=\mathcal{O}(a) \oplus  \mathcal{O}(b)$, we have $$\pi_1^*E|_{X_t} = F|_{X_t}= \mathcal{O}(a) \oplus  \mathcal{O}(b)$$ for every $t$. However, the two vector bundles  $F$ and $E\boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(k)$ can never be isomorphic, since the former is indecomposable whereas the latter is decomposable.

**References.**

**[1]** *Ballico, Edoardo*, Uniform vector bundles on quadrics, Ann. Univ. Ferrara, N. Ser., Sez. VII 27, 135-146 (1981). [ZBL0495.14008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0495.14008).